# LINQ to SQL Classes Template missing

Tags: windows-phone-8, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 application. I was going to use LINQ to SQL Classes Template to generate my O/R mapping but it is not listed in Visual C# Items. However, this template appears when I'm in a WinForms Project. 
I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2013 with the Windows Phone 8 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202872%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is the detail of using LINQ-to-SQL in Windows Phone.

Comment: This topic doesn't mention anything about the template.